# How can i get facebook access token from facebook user id?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am working on the application which has some condition that I have to pass facebook token to web service but I have an only facebook id which is store in user model, So is there any way in Facebook SDK to get facebook access token from facebook id?

Comment: I think, this is a valid question. As seems questioner want to know another way to have access token which is not possible except @luschn answer, So I'vent found any way to make it minus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the access token when the user authorizes your App. There is no way to just generate it with the id, it can only happen on user interaction.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens